# Why can't I use a list comprehension in this function?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am working on a little practice problem where the program must accept words from the user until the user enters a simple space, and put them in a list removing duplicates. I have found out how to do it but I would like to incorporate a list comprehension. The first block is the working program, the second provides a `SyntaxError`

```
userinput = None
lst = []
while userinput != " ":
    userinput = input("enter a word: ")
    if userinput not in lst:
        lst.append(userinput)
for word in lst:
    print(word)
```

```
userinput = None
lst = []
while userinput != " ":
    userinput = input("enter a word: ")
    [lst.append(userinput) if userinput not in lst] # Here is my comprehension
for word in lst:
    print(word)
```

Comment: A list comprehension needs `for something in somethingelse`

Comment: Because the format of a list comprehension is `[expression for member in iterable]`.

Comment: Check the [docs on list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: The whole point of a list comprehension is to make a new list from an existing collection or sequence of things. If you're not assigning the result to something, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Your first code is the way to do it, although I'd use a set to remove duplicates automatically.  List comprehension is not needed or desired in this case.

Comment: To add to @MarkTolonen 's comment, list comprehension is also impossible for your logic as it can't break as per your `while` condition.

Comment: Thank you very much all, I have learned more than I originally came for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the list comprehensions is invalid
you can use a list comprehensions as:

```
[item for item in list]
```

with an if statement

```
[item for item in list if True]     # with a if statement.
```

but in your example you can also use

```
userinput = None
lst = []
while userinput != " ":
    userinput = input("enter a word: ")
    lst.append(userinput)

lst = list(set(lst))
```

this wil change the list to an set and remove all duplicated values

I think this is an ineteresting topic about list-comprehension:
https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/

another option with set given by Yevhen Kuzmovych is:

```
userinput = None
lst = set()
while userinput != " ":
    userinput = input("enter a word: ")
    lst.add(userinput)

for word in lst:
    print(word)
```

Comment: You can just have a `set` in the first place. And `.add` values to it

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions work with this for format.

```
[element for element in iterable]
```

They are essentially condensed `for` loops so they require both `for` and `in` statements against an iterable.

For this purpose you could actually use a **ternary operator** if you just want to condense the logic to 1 line

```
lst.append(userinput) if userinput not in lst else None
```

Comment: @NickA you could use a ternary operator, but you shouldn't. Your first block is the way to go.

Comment: Why shouldn't you? Genuinely curious.

Comment: Should have mentioned that it is just my opinion. But the ternary operator is very expression-like structure, meaning that its result is something to be used later which in this case might be confusing.

Comment: Interesting! So just for my understanding, something like `check = True if condition else False` , where `check` is used later in the code, would be a more appropriate use of the operator in your opinion?

Comment: In this particular case `check = condition` would be better :). But I get what you are saying. Yes, it is an appropriate use of the ternary operator. Because it simplifies something like `if condition: check = True; else: check = False`. While the OPs case would look and work much simpler with the regular `if` statement.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you for answering!